# Table beside a floating element

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a floating element on the right (size may vary). I want to display a table left of it using all available remaing space. Furthermore, the table columns need to be proportional, so I need table-layout:fixed.

(Since all solutions so far are workarounds, I would like to make my point more clear: The floating element does not have a fixed size. Therefore all solutions with margin-right, width:x % or witdh:x px will either leave screen areas unused or cut/overwrite the element.)

Is it possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/GunnarB/3ZYq8/

```
select {
    float:right;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color:gray;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
}
#wrapper table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#00FFFF;
}
td {
    padding:5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

<select size="3">
<option>DB entries with unknown width</option>
<option>h--p://www.google.com</option>
<option>h--p://www.msn.com</option>
</select>    
<div id="wrapper">
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>left</td>
            <td>some text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>left</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>left</td>
            <td>NG</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for (no width declaration with 100% width on the image and a div that fills in the rest of the space) can be done with just CSS. It shouldn't be too bad to do in javascript/jQuery if you're willing to go that route.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. I was just thinking, if you have normal text instead of a table the text is wrapped when there is no more space. Therefore the browser must calculate the width of the remaining space. Should be usable as table width (automatically, not by javascript).

Comment: Have any of the answers been found acceptable?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify width to the image and the div.

Update your CSS like this -

```
img {
    float:right;
    width: 40%;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color:gray;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

This should work!

Comment: While it is possible, if the image only uses 10% of the screen, I would waste 30%. That is not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Specify width to the #wrapper

```
#wrapper {
  background-color:gray;
  padding:5px;
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZppLh/

**HTML**

```
<img src="whatever">
<div id="wrapper">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>left</td>
    <td>some text</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>left</td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>left</td>
    <td>NG</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    float:right;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color:gray;
    right: 285px;
    position: absolute;
}
#wrapper table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#00FFFF;
}
td {
    padding:5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Comment: This solution won't work for images larger than 285px.

Comment: I thought the idea of floating elements is that the content automatically floats around it. Defining a fixed size works for this image, but as I wrote: floating element is of variable size.

Comment: @GunnarBernstein If you have really an  image there, you must know its width. please be exact when posting your question.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok the idea behind `285px` is that you know the width of your image

Comment: @Arash Read the first sentence of the question. He doesn't know the image size. It's really not that unreasonable of a request.

Comment: you may use my solution, in addition to lines of javascript to change `#wrapper` 's `right`, according to image's width.

Comment: @Arash While true, if Gunnar is already using javascript it would be better to not use absolute positioning (this situation isn't really what absolute positioning is used for). He might as well just set the image to be 100% width and then set the height of the table.

Comment: The float element is actually a list of text entries with variable length. While I know the maximum width I would like to use as much space as possible if the list is thin. I updated the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's another approach](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZYq8/105/) using CSS only. The HTML is identical to the original, so I won't quote it again here. There are just a couple of changes to the CSS. The key here is to *not* float the container for the table, and apply `overflow: hidden` to its wrapper.

```
select {
    float:right;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color:gray;
    padding:5px;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#00FFFF;
}
td {
    padding:5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

You'd probably want to encapsulate the whole thing (`select` and `table`) in a `div` wrapper to give you control over how you want to use it in context in your page.

Comment: This actually works. I need to look at the page to see what it does to the rest as it is not floating anymore.

Comment: @GunnarBernstein you might need to wrap the whole thing above in a `div` which could "protect" the rest of the page.

Comment: @GunnarBernstein so what's the verdict? :)